# With a directory full of millions of files, what is the most efficient way to download, process, and delete the files in manageable batches?

Tags: ssh, scp

I’ve been handed a flat directory full of millions of files on a remote server that need to be processed (let’s just say I have to run a script called `doThingsToTheFile.sh` on each file). I can `ssh` into the machine to prep the files (modify the directory structure, zip files, etc.), but for reasons beyond the scope of this question, I can only run the script on my local machine. Unfortunately, I don’t have enough local space to `scp` the entire directory.

My plan is to `scp` batches of n files at a time, process them, delete them from the local machine, and repeat. What is the most efficient way to do this? Or is there a better way entirely?

Comment: Please define "process the files"

Comment: I purposefully left it vague because the details are beyond the scope of the question. Let’s just say I have to run a script called `doThingsToTheFile.sh`on each file, and the script can’t be run on the server

Comment: Delete from server or just local machine?

Comment: Just the local machine

Comment: if you have a reliable network connection one option is to mount it: `sshfs -o ro server:/remote/path /local/path` and treat like a normal local directory. Depends what you're trying to optimise.